# Send XML from Server Side to CLient Side

Tags: java, c#, jquery, vb.net

Any one help Me,..

strFileName ="C:\xmlTest.xml" 
 Dim dsEqp As new DataSet 
 dsEqp.Tables.Add("TEST") 
 dsEqp.WriteXml(strFileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)

how to send the XML File, from server to folder Client computer ?

Please Help

here my code

```
    Dim strActualProdID As String
    strActualProdID = Trim(Me.lblactualprodid.Text) & "_status.xml"
    Dim bl_other As New BusinessLayer.clsPCMonthlyProductionPlan
    Dim strFileName As String
    strFileName = bl_other.ExportFolder(Me.Session("authstate")) & "\" & strActualProdID

    tabActual.Tabs.FromKeyTab("tabstatus").ContentPane.UserControlUrl = ".\ctlPC_ActualEqpEvent.ascx"
    ctrl_ProdStatus = CType(Me.tabActual.Tabs.FromKeyTab("tabstatus").ContentPane.UserControl, ctlPC_ActualEqpEvent)

    Dim dsEqpStatus As DataSet = ctrl_ProdStatus.getTransAddData()
    dsEqpStatus.WriteXml(strFileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)


    Dim objStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    dsEqpStatus.WriteXml(objStream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
    Dim client As New WebClient
    client.DownloadFile(strFileName, "C:\CMOSDIR\" & strActualProdID)
    client.Dispose()
```

Comment: Please format your code. Also besides asking how to do it, rather you need to research first and try it. Then if you get stuck ask us for help. Thank you.

Comment: that is my code, but the xml file can't save on the client.